# Trinidad Tobago Coordinate Reference System

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, trinidad-tobago

I am currently hoping to set up a map of the North of Tobago with the amphibian species which are present there.

I am very new to QGIS and am unsure how to get Tobago as a projection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most recent one that the EPSG registry has is Naparima 1972 / UTM zone 20N, EPSG::27120. WGS 84 / UTM zone 20N is generic and probably not used officially by the government. For non-government usage, just using it is probably fine as suggested by @Spacedman.